# Multiple Achievements Earned at Once with Openfeint

Tags: iphone, openfeint, achievements

I have a scenario where it's possible to earn > 1 achievement at the same time.  Has anyone come across a good solution for displaying them using OpenFeint?  Right now OpenFeint shows 2 overlapping each other -- not that helpful for the user.  I'm wondering if OpenFeint has a built-in system for handling this, rather than having to write the delay code on my end.  Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a built-in solution -- looks like the only way to do this is to customize the achievement alerts and DIY.